# Android: Play video in Background

Tags: android, video, service

I have one big question: "How do you let videos play in your app while going to other apps?"
I saw Act 1 `Video Player` do it but how do you do it?

Comment: Why would you want to play video in background?

Comment: I want to stream a youtube video but i can't get the mp3 so i have to stream the video but how do i stream in in the background

Comment: Don't think it's a nice solution cause you'll be fetching a lot more data than you actually need and I don't think your users will like it.